# Why is "update foo ... where bar is null" letting multiple callers claim the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, updates, galera

I have a fairly basic query:

```
UPDATE the_table SET col1=[something], col2=[something else] WHERE col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Immediately after issuing the query, the caller does:

```
SELECT col3 FROM the_table where col1=[something], col2=[something else];
```

Unfortunately, concurrent callers are claiming the same row.

I'd rather not do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, because the [select, update, select] would involve three rpcs to the database instead of two (which is bad enough.)

I gather that some dialects of sql allow `UPDATE the_table WITH(UPDLOCK)`, but mine (galera/MySQL) does not. I find it appalling that I'd have to go through this many DB hits to execute such a basic concept. I find that most of my searching efforts end on pages that discuss dialects that DO support UPDLOCK.

Where does it go from here?

Comment: Can you use `select for update` to retrieve `col3`, then update the row? Still only two calls. Also, you can't send two statements in the same batch?

Comment: You can code a stored procedure that would do job inside a `transaction`.  Just one call and safe with concurrency.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Problem 1: The `SELECT` will be empty-handed; Problem 2: "batch" has to be a transaction, which means 4 commands (after adding `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`).

Comment: @RickJames - not the select in the OP, `select for update` with where clause from the OP's `update` statement, to lock the row. And 4 commands but one round trip, which is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `autocommit=1`?

Without transactional integrity, some other connection can slip in and change the row before *you* execute the `SELECT`.

Note that there could be multiple NULL rows, so the `UPDATE` may be changing many rows.

Did you check the "rows affected" after the `UPDATE`?  Maybe no rows were changed.

Comment: There's a `limit 1` on the end of that update statement

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be better to either execute all the queries in a transaction or to use a stored proc which will be responsible to make all the select and update stuff and then return back to you the respective data from the last select statement. Having such a flow out of transaction, raises issues as the one you describe. You need to lock the row in order not to allow other callers retrieve "dirty" (not up to date) data.